# Evaluating $T(n)=2^n+4T(\frac{n}{2})$

Tags: recurrence-relation

$$T(n)=2^n+4T(\frac{n}{2})$$

I have started substitution for:

$$T(\frac{n}{2})=2^{\frac{n}{2}}+4T(\frac{n}{4})$$

$$T(\frac{n}{4})=2^{\frac{n}{4}}+4T(\frac{n}{8})$$

$$...$$

$$T(\frac{n}{4})=2^n+4[2^{\frac{n}{2}}+4(2^{\frac{n}{4}}+4T(\frac{n}{8}))]=2^n+4\cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}+4^2\cdot 2^{\frac{n}{4}}+4^3T(\frac{n}{8})$$

So in general:

$$T(\frac{n}{2^k})=2^n+4\cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}+...+4^k\cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2^k}}+4^{k+1}T(\frac{n}{2^{k+1}})$$

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: You should see that the lower terms are _nothing_ compared to the 2^n factor.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's more easy to take $n=2^k$ and write substitution in following way:
$$\begin{array}{l}T(n)=2^2 T\left(\frac{n}{2} \right)+2^n=2^2\left[2^2T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^2} \right) +2^{\frac{n}{2}}\right]+2^n=\\
=2^{2 \cdot 2}T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^2} \right)+2^{2+\frac{n}{2}}+2^n=2^{2 \cdot 2}\left[2^2T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^{3}} \right) +2^{\frac{n}{4}}\right]+2^{2+\frac{n}{2}}+2^n=\\
=2^{2 \cdot 3}T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^{3}} \right) + 2^{4+\frac{n}{4}}+2^{2+\frac{n}{2}}+2^n=\\
=\cdots =\\ 
=2^{2 \cdot k}T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^{k}} \right) + 2^{2(k-1)+\frac{n}{2^{k-1}}}+\cdots+2^{2+\frac{n}{2}}+2^n = \\
=n^2T(1)+ 2^{2(k-1)+\frac{n}{2^{k-1}}}+\cdots+2^{2+\frac{n}{2}}+2^n
\end{array}
$$
rough estimation of $T(n)$ is $O(2^n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T(n)=T(2^m)=:P(m)$. The recurrence becomes

$$P(m)=2^{2^m}+4P(m-1).$$

Now we try to solve by the method of variation of the constant, noticing that a solution of the homogeneous equation is $P(m)=4^m$.

$$C(m)4^m=2^{2^m}+C(m-1)4^m$$ or

$$C(m)=C(m-1)+2^{2^m-2m}.$$

Then

$$C(m)=C(0)+\sum_{k=1}^m2^{2^k-2m},$$
$$P(m)=C(0)4^m+\sum_{k=1}^m2^{2^k},$$
and
$$T(n)=C(0)n^2+\sum_{k=1}^{\lg n}2^{2^k}=C(0)n^2+4+16+256+\cdots 2^n.$$

For sufficiently large $n$, the sum is very close to its last term, and

$$T(n)\approx 2^n.$$